# how to change branch on --bare remote from local in git

Tags: linux, git, repository, hook

I am trying to make a hook on a remote --bare repository that will copy the source code I send from a local git, in different folders according the branch I'm sending to. I have 3 branches on local: master, development and release so I wish that on the remote would be 3 folders containing the source code of each branch. I found that using:

> git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD

in combination with a series of if conditions could do the trick. The only problem is that the HEAD remains the same on remote for whatever branch you send to. Is there any code that could be used in the hook, so it would know that I am sending to a certain branch? Or is there any other method for doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your one bare repo will have all 3 branches on it. You can use git modifiers like this to make 3 separate directories update to what each branch contains:

```
git --work-tree=/some/project/dir/branch1 --git-dir=/path/to/bare/repo checkout branch1 -- .
```

To avoid specifying those options, you can set their corresponding environment variables:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE
GIT_DIR
```

This way you can keep one bare repo and 3 separate directories that update when branches are pushed. Remember what the arguments are that are provided in your hook. The first is the branch name.